# Is there a mod_sed equivalent for Tomcat?

Tags: apache, tomcat

[mod_sed](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_sed.html) allows you to modify the bodies of HTTP requests in Apache. Is there a similar tool in Apache Tomcat ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomcat is different from Apache (even if it's Apache Tomcat). I'm not aware of something like mod_sed.

The two options that I can think of are:

- Dependending of what you need to do, if you want to modify input (request), you can get the Entity from the HttpServletRequest, and modify it. Also, if you want to modify the response, well, you can create the response on the server side in your Java code, but then you can also access the HttpServletResponse.
- Another option would be to use nginx to proxy all request to your Tomcat, and do the magic in nginx. I think ngx_http_sub_module lets you do what you want in nginx.

But basically, if you're using servlets, you have full control of the data that goes into the servlet and then you can craft your response with the data you want, so I don't really see the need for that sed functionality here (maybe it's because I would need more information to see the big picture).